# How to resolve Invalid Hadoop Yarn Home error

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop on CentOS7, following steps here - https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-centos-7 (Only difference Hadoop version is 3.2.1 instead of 2.7.3 in article)

I followed everything precisely until at step 4 when i type in "hadoop" in terminal it gives me an error - ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_YARN_HOME

Is there any setup related to Yarn thats needed? I read the Apache doc and other links on the web but they all mention only JAVA_HOME path is needed which I did set as per above link.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The environment variables changed in Hadoop 3. Try again with actually using Hadoop 2.7.3 or find another tutorial (such as the official Apache one)

Comment: @cricket_007, thank you so much...i tried with 2.7.3 and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Open `~/.bashrc`

add

```
export HADOOP_HOME=path_to_your_hadoop_package
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
```